# why marginTop not working in using nth-of-type?

Tags: html, css

i have added margin top using **nth-of-type** why it is not applied ?but it working find when I am passing value `3` why ?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    .rc105 .rc105-subheader:nth-of-type(2) {
      margin-top: 32px;
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="rc105 rc105v0" >
  <div class="cwidth">
    <div class="rc105-subheader">
      <div class="rc105-ttl">
         Applications
      </div>
      <p class="desc"> together.
        <a href="#" class="link">Learn more </a></p>
    </div>


    <div class="rc105w1 rw-scrim-neutral-40bg">
    </div>

    <div class="rc105-subheader">
      <div class="rc105-ttl">
        Test
      </div>
      <p class="desc"> platform.
        <a href="#" class="link">Learn</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="rc105w1 rw-scrim-neutral-40bg">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nth-of-type is referring to the element type, in this case a `div`.

It is not referring to the nth instance of that class in the selector.

The 3 works because the class you are targeting is the 3rd `div` in that node. The 2 doesn't work because the second div does not have that class, it has some `rw-scrim-neutral-40bg` class.

It is typically more common to see nth-of-type used with the element in the selector, e.g. `div:nth-of-type(#)` or `p.something:nth-of-type(#)`

Comment: any better solution to pick second `rc105-subheader`

Comment: It's really not possible to do that. Your best bet is to either use nth-child/nth-of-type with the correct node index; or, use some sort adjacent/sibling selector, e.g. `.rc105-subheader + div + .rc105-subheader` or `.rc105-subheader ~ .rc105-subheader` but those have their own drawbacks as well. If you can use JavaScript, you can loop through the subheaders and add another class to it or style it accordingly.